# Is a single edge between two vertices equivalent to two directed edges in opposite directions?

Tags: graph-theory

I've just begun my journey on learning Graph Theory and was just wondering whether these two can be seen as equivalent or not:

A single edge between two vertices (A and B): [As seen here](https://i.gyazo.com/ed808852580fa13de4e45cb2d77b366c.png)

**Is equivalent to?:**

Two directed edges (both in opposite directions from vertices A and B): [As seen here](https://i.gyazo.com/a2f825550fb5edfa968aabe1826fe859.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no relation between the two graphs that you have described.

You are trying to identify two different concepts.

We have directed graphs and graphs which are not directed.

In a directed graph you may have one or more directed edges connect two vertices.
You may also have a loop in a non directed graph.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for the reply!

Comment: Thanks for your attention.